# Access nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

im having real trouble to complete an FullStackOpen exersice, it requires to render some data to the page. Give the next code, i have to render the number of `Parts` that each `Course` has, and also so reduce the number of `Parts/Exersices` to render the total of exersices por each Course.

I am not being able to reach the inside of the Parts array of objects

````
    {
      name: "Half Stack application development",
      id: 1,
      parts: [
        {
          name: "Fundamentals of React",
          exercises: 10,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Using props to pass data",
          exercises: 7,
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "State of a component",
          exercises: 14,
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          name: "Redux",
          exercises: 11,
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Node.js",
      id: 2,
      parts: [
        {
          name: "Routing",
          exercises: 3,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          name: "Middlewares",
          exercises: 7,
          id: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that difficult, for each element of the array:

- number of parts is `currentElement.parts.length`
- number of exercises can be computed using `Array.reduce`

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Half Stack application development",
    id: 1,
    parts: [{
        name: "Fundamentals of React",
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Using props to pass data",
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "State of a component",
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Redux",
        exercises: 11,
        id: 4,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Node.js",
    id: 2,
    parts: [{
        name: "Routing",
        exercises: 3,
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "Middlewares",
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const res = []

for (const course of data) {
  const tmpObj = {
    courseName: course.name,
    parts: course.parts.length,
    exercises: course.parts.reduce((a,b) => a + b.exercises, 0)
  }
  
  res.push(tmpObj)
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a total number of exercises per course, you will need to reduce each by name; and for each list of parts, reduce by the exercise count.

```js
const main = () => {
  const courseData = courses.map(({ name, parts }) => ({
    name,
    parts: parts.length,
    exercises: parts.reduce((sum, { exercises }) => sum + exercises, 0)
  }));
  
  console.log(courseData);
};

const courses = [{
  name: "Half Stack application development",
  id: 1,
  parts: [
    { name: "Fundamentals of React"    , exercises: 10 , id: 1 },
    { name: "Using props to pass data" , exercises:  7 , id: 2 },
    { name: "State of a component"     , exercises: 14 , id: 3 },
    { name: "Redux"                    , exercises: 11 , id: 4 }
  ],
}, {
  name: "Node.js",
  id: 2,
  parts: [
    { name: "Routing"     , exercises: 3 , id: 1 },
    { name: "Middlewares" , exercises: 7 , id: 2 }
  ],
}];

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```